# Passing json_encoded array to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to pass an array I am creating in PHP using `json_encode()`. I am running an AJAX request, see as follows:

**AJAX CALL:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/ajax.php?imagemeta=1",
        data: {
            'id' : $(this).attr('id')
        },
        datatype:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data["image_height"]);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

**PHP JSON RESPONSE:**

```
if(isset($_GET["imagemeta"])){

$id = intval($_POST["id"]);
$path = "../uploads/images/" . $fm->selectImageById($id);
$meta = array();

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);
$meta["image_height"]   = $height . 'px';
$meta["image_width"]    = $width . 'px';

print json_encode($meta);
```

}

Although, the console.log(data) returns the following: `{"image_height":"1374px","image_width":"920px"}`

The following line console.log(data["image_height"]) returns undefined.

I have tried multiple attempts and have read through majority of the top rated questions regarding the subject. I am fairly new with JSON encoding so please inform me if I have a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: Try `data.image_height`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
datatype:"json",
```

should be:

```
dataType:"json",
    ^
```

Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I hate my minor errors that throw me off for hours. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

If console.log displaying you following:-

```
{"image_height":"1374px","image_width":"920px"}
```

Then you can access "image_height" as follows:-

```
data.image_height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set php JSON response header or return plain text from php and use $.parseJSON in success function.

```
 success: function(data) {
        jSon = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(jSon.image_height);
    }
```